# Naive question about product topology vs quotient topology

Tags: general-topology, product-space

I have a very naive question about the product topology. Whenever I see a topological space with a product topology structure, this structure is already explicitly given. That is, the statement will begin something like "$X\times Y$ be a topological space...". My question is somehow "(how) can you know a topological space has a product structure?". If you are given a topological space X, are there some necessary and/or sufficient conditions which allow you to test whether there is a non-trivial Y and Z such that $X\cong Y\times Z$?

My naive guess would go something like: Let $X$ be a topological space (maybe with some special structure).
Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation (maybe with some special structure) and $X/\sim$ be the equivalence classes equipped with the quotient topology.
Now consider each $[x]\in X/\sim$ as a subset of $X$, and equip each of theses subsets with the subset topology.
Then, if $[x]$ is homeomorphic to some topological space $Y$, $\forall [x]\in X/\sim$, then $X \cong X/\sim \times Y$?

I'd guess this isn't true, but I haven't been able to come up with (what i am sure is) an obvious counter example. I believe my intuition about product spaces vs quotient spaces is deeply flawed, so some thoughts on this would also be appreciated.

Comment: Determining whether or not $X$ is an interesting product is a very hard question.

Comment: Even determining if a space if of the form $X \times X$ is very hard and technical (there's a popular math overflow question on it), and determining other product structures is only going to be more complicated

Comment: The product topology is the smallest topology that makes each projection map continuous. So the first question would be if the space has a product structure that gives us projection maps. Then, given the projection maps, what topology makes them continuous?

Comment: This is not a naïve question at all, it's an excellent question!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the Mobius strip and let $p\colon\mathcal{M}\to S^1$ be the map that retracts the Mobius strip in its central circle. I define the equivalence relation on $\mathcal{M}$:
$$x\sim y \iff p(x)=p(y).$$

Can you see that this is a counterexample?

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the quick response! Yes, if I understand correctly, then when you try to build back the space you get [0,1]x[0,1]. Somehow, in very hand-wavey terms, equivalence relation 'destroys' the global topological information (the twist).

Comment: I think you're understanding this much more than you're giving yourself credit for.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if im meant to ask follow up questions in the comments here. I'm also not really sure how to phrase this. This particular equivalence relation doesn't seem to tell us much about the original space? It kinda destroys everything. Are there known equivalence relations that are useful for investigating the properties of topological spaces? I'm thinking something analagous to looking for normal subgroups. (I appreciate if this question makes sense, its possibly very vague).

Comment: @GeorgeKenworthy Spot on! Basically in your question you are cutting in hoemomorphic slices the space $X$ through an equivalence relation and the topology of the quotient space dictates how this slices are glued together. But this gluing doesn't necessarily correspond to the gluing of the slices that you had in the beginning.  Nevertheless the example that I wrote in my answer is still kinda nice because at least locally the two gluings are the same (do you see it?).

Comment: @GeorgeKenworthy If you wanted an even more patological example just take a circle and attach to each point of it a segment in a totally randomic way (the only conditions is that the segments should be disjoint). Doing so you obtain an infinite family of arbitrarily pathological counterexamples.